# DateTime formating

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `CultureInfo()` to get format of `DateTime`

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
someDateTime.ToString("d", culture));
```

How to get custom formats and not to lose separator which comes with `CultureInfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator?view=net-6.0#remarks) for `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator`:

> If a custom format string includes the "/" format specifier, the DateTime.ToString method displays the value of DateSeparator in place of the "/" in the result string.

So just use a [custom date/time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) with slashes, and they will be replaced automatically.

Example:

```
var someDateTime = new DateTime(1900, 12, 21);
Console.WriteLine(someDateTime.ToString("d/M", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
Console.WriteLine(someDateTime.ToString("d/M", new CultureInfo("nl")));
Console.WriteLine(someDateTime.ToString("yyy/M", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
Console.WriteLine(someDateTime.ToString("yyy/M", new CultureInfo("nl")));
```

Output:

```
21/12
21-12
1900/12
1900-12
```

Just be aware that this probably isn't a great idea. The separator is not the only meaningful difference between cultures' date representations. `5/6` means May 6 to Americans, but it means June 5 to most Europeans (even those which use the same date separator).

Comment: I misinterpreted this piece of documentation earlier. Thanks :) @StriplingWarrior

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a format when you call `ToString` on `DateTime` objects.
e.g.:

`someDateTime.ToString("MM-yyyy"); // produces a formatted date like 12-1900`

Formatting Info: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: But then you inputs separator. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the separator property of the DateTimeFormatInfo object, like so:

```
DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";

someDateTime.ToString("d", culture);
```

Comment: okey and is there a way to make it without specify the separator ?